# Is the following quantifier capturing the variables correctly?

Tags: logic, divisibility

Consider the following statement.

```
d|n -> for all d, there exist k n = dk (divisibility)
```

In words it is:

```
if d divides n then for every d (which divides n), there is a k 
such that n is a product of d and k.
```

Is the above statement aligned with the explanation?

what are the other mathematical forms, I can write the above statement?

Comment: There is no reason to assume $d$ is universally quantified.  But if you were, then whatever reason you had for assuming $d$ was universally quantified would apply to $n$ as well.  Just leave $d$ and $n$ as unquantified free variables.

Comment: The universal quantifiers must have the complete formula as *scope*: $\forall d \ \forall n \ (d|n \leftrightarrow \exists k \ (n=dk))$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA d and n is undefined in this case? So is this statement completely wrong if we say that d and n are not quantified

Comment: @DanielV what is will be the meaning of this statement if we leave both variables d and n unquantified? Please, can you elaborate the difference between unquantified and quantified variables?

Comment: The leftmost $d$ (the free one) is not "the same" as the quantified one: $\forall d \ \exists k \ (n=kd)$ - for fixed $n$ - is false.

Comment: It is a bit confusing what you are asking for.  Are you trying to translate "$d|n$" into predicate logic?  Or are you trying to translate "d|n -> for all d, there exist k n = dk (divisibility)" into English?  Or are you trying to verify whether "for all d, there exist k n = dk (divisibility)" is a correct definition of $|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be written as:

$$d|n \iff \exists k[k \in \mathbb{Z} \land n = dk]$$

where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers. It's also must be the true that $d \neq 0$, but that possibility is eliminated by the fact that if it were, $k$ would be undefined so $k \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

The idea of divisibility can also be written in terms of the modulo operator:

$$n \bmod d = 0$$